# Connected through VNC the keyboard language changes inside a virtualBox machine

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, vnc

Hi all I'm having this problem and I cannot find a solution.

**The problem:**

When I connect to my server using VNC and after that I started a virtual machine from VirtualBox the keyboard of the virtual machine is changed and I cannot change it. If I type in the host I still have my original keyboard settings.

**Trials:**

I've checked [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15077) old thread and when I execute the next command:

```
LOG_KB_SECONDARY=1 VirtualBox -startvm <your VM name>
```

I get the following:

```
Attempting to match against "U.S. English"
Matches=47, seq=33
Attempting to match against "U.S. English, International (with dead keys)"
Matches=44, seq=31
...
Excluded more attempts
...
Detected layout is "U.S. English", matches=47, seq=33
Warning - keycode 17, keysym "0)" (0x30 0x29) was matched to scancode 11
Warning - keycode 18, keysym "1!" (0x31 0x21) was matched to scancode 2
Warning - keycode 19, keysym "2@" (0x32 0x40) was matched to scancode 3
Warning - keycode 20, keysym "3#" (0x33 0x23) was matched to scancode 4
Warning - keycode 21, keysym "4$" (0x34 0x24) was matched to scancode 5
Warning - keycode 22, keysym "5%" (0x35 0x25) was matched to scancode 6
Warning - keycode 23, keysym "6^" (0x36 0x5e) was matched to scancode 7
Warning - keycode 24, keysym "7&" (0x37 0x26) was matched to scancode 8
Warning - keycode 25, keysym "8*" (0x38 0x2a) was matched to scancode 9
Warning - keycode 26, keysym "9(" (0x39 0x28) was matched to scancode 10
Warning - keycode 27, keysym "-_" (0x2d 0x5f) was matched to scancode 12
Warning - keycode 28, keysym "=+" (0x3d 0x2b) was matched to scancode 13
Warning - keycode 29, keysym "[{" (0x5b 0x7b) was matched to scancode 26
Warning - keycode 30, keysym "]}" (0x5d 0x7d) was matched to scancode 27
Warning - keycode 31, keysym ";:" (0x3b 0x3a) was matched to scancode 39
Warning - keycode 32, keysym "'"" (0x27 0x22) was matched to scancode 40
Warning - keycode 33, keysym "`~" (0x60 0x7e) was matched to scancode 41
Warning - keycode 34, keysym ",<" (0x2c 0x3c) was matched to scancode 51
Warning - keycode 35, keysym ".>" (0x2e 0x3e) was matched to scancode 52
Warning - keycode 36, keysym "/?" (0x2f 0x3f) was matched to scancode 53
Warning - keycode 37, keysym "\|" (0x5c 0x7c) was matched to scancode 43
Warning - keycode 39, keysym "bB" (0x62 0x42) was matched to scancode 48
Warning - keycode 40, keysym "cC" (0x63 0x43) was matched to scancode 46
Warning - keycode 41, keysym "dD" (0x64 0x44) was matched to scancode 32
Warning - keycode 42, keysym "eE" (0x65 0x45) was matched to scancode 18
Warning - keycode 43, keysym "fF" (0x66 0x46) was matched to scancode 33
Warning - keycode 44, keysym "gG" (0x67 0x47) was matched to scancode 34
Warning - keycode 45, keysym "hH" (0x68 0x48) was matched to scancode 35
Warning - keycode 46, keysym "iI" (0x69 0x49) was matched to scancode 23
Warning - keycode 47, keysym "jJ" (0x6a 0x4a) was matched to scancode 36
Warning - keycode 48, keysym "kK" (0x6b 0x4b) was matched to scancode 37
Warning - keycode 49, keysym "lL" (0x6c 0x4c) was matched to scancode 38
Warning - keycode 50, keysym "mM" (0x6d 0x4d) was matched to scancode 50
Warning - keycode 51, keysym "nN" (0x6e 0x4e) was matched to scancode 49
Warning - keycode 52, keysym "oO" (0x6f 0x4f) was matched to scancode 24
Warning - keycode 53, keysym "pP" (0x70 0x50) was matched to scancode 25
Warning - keycode 54, keysym "qQ" (0x71 0x51) was matched to scancode 16
Warning - keycode 55, keysym "rR" (0x72 0x52) was matched to scancode 19
Warning - keycode 56, keysym "sS" (0x73 0x53) was matched to scancode 31
Warning - keycode 57, keysym "tT" (0x74 0x54) was matched to scancode 20
Warning - keycode 58, keysym "uU" (0x75 0x55) was matched to scancode 22
Warning - keycode 59, keysym "vV" (0x76 0x56) was matched to scancode 47
Warning - keycode 60, keysym "wW" (0x77 0x57) was matched to scancode 17
Warning - keycode 61, keysym "xX" (0x78 0x58) was matched to scancode 45
Warning - keycode 62, keysym "yY" (0x79 0x59) was matched to scancode 21
Warning - keycode 63, keysym "zZ" (0x7a 0x5a) was matched to scancode 44
Finished mapping keyboard, matches=47, entries=47 (excluding 102nd key)
```

I guess VirtualBox cannot detect the proper keyboard setting. When I execute the very same command in the server (without using VNC) I get a completely different output and the keyboard is correctly detected.

**Interesting data:**

- Host: Ubuntu 14.04
- Guest: Several ones (Lubuntu, Ubuntu 14.04, among others)
- VirtualBox version: 5.0.8